# Delete vector-elements of (dangling) pointers after deallocating

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

After deallocated memory on the heap - the vector still holds (dangling) pointers in the vector. How do I completely delete the vector-elements?

```
vector<Obstacle*> obstacles; 
vector<Action*> actions;  

void Game::free(GameFactory *gFact) {

   obstacles = gFact->getObstacles();
   actions = gFact->getActions();
   destroyVectorElements(obstacles);
   destroyVectorElements(actions);
}

template<typename T>
void destroyVectorElements(vector<T> &vec) {
  typename vector<T>::iterator start=vec.begin(), stop=vec.end(), it;
  for(it=start; it!=stop; ++it) {
    delete (*it);
  }
}
```

The deallocation works but  the vector-list is still there with dangling pointers.

Comment: like you'd delete any other vector elements??

Comment: With your sample code, there's *no need* to remove the elements from the vectors - the vectors go out of scope immediately after the call to `destroyVectorElements`, so there's no danger of dereferencing any of them.

Answer (score 3):

Call vec.clear() after the deleting iteration.

```
template<typename T>
void destroyVectorElements(vector<T> &vec) {
  typename vector<T>::iterator start=vec.begin(), stop=vec.end(), it;
  for(it=start; it!=stop; ++it) {
    delete (*it);
  }
  vec.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this while iterating (useful if you need to `delete` a subrange), call `erase` after you `delete` the pointer. Note that you'll also need to recalculate `vec.end()` because the iterator will be invalidated:

```
template<typename T>
void destroyVectorElements(vector<T> &vec) {
  typename vector<T>::iterator start=vec.begin(), it;
  for(it=start; it!=vec.end(); ++it) {
    delete (*it);
    it = vec.erase(it);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could just call `clear` after carrying out your iteration.

Or, you could (and should) just sidestep the whole issue by using `std::unique_ptr` (or `std::shared_ptr` if you have shared ownership).

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the difference between what elements are actually held in the vector vs what the elements held in vector are pointing to. In your case vector elements are pointers to dynamically allocated objects. Calling delete on these will release the heap memory but vector elements themselves remain untouched.

Call  `vec.clear()`  on the vector to clear it's content.